# How can I get Windows proprietary software over Wine to reach its hardware by polling on the right USB port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, wine

Over a year ago I was trying to get a Windows proprietary application, that polls USB ports to get information from a series of sensors, [to work on a Linux machine using Wine](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=697238&page=4).

I wasn't able to solve the problem and I had to use a Windows license.  However, I am still stuck with having that hardware work under Linux (and at this moment, a Windows license is a much less preferable answer.)

The application just says that "no USB device was found" and asks me to check if the driver is installed or if the device is connected. This is the same error I get in Windows when the device is not connected. No driver installation is required in Windows. Currently I have no other software or hardware that I can use to test from Wine.

How can I get that Windows proprietary over Wine software to reach its hardware by polling on the right USB port?

Comment: By "pooling" do you actually mean "[Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science))"?  What exactly happens when you try it in Wine?  Can you successfully access the a more common USB device (say a flash drive) from Wine?

Comment: Right, @techie007.  Polling corrected.  Than you. -- The application just say that there are no USB device was found and ask me to check if the driver is installed or if the device is connected.  This is the same error I get in Windows when the device is not connected.  No driver installation is required in Windows.  Currently I have no other sw/hw that I can use to test from Wine.

Comment: @techie007, I inserted a pendrive and (as expected) it didn't create a new letter in the windows emulated environment.  It could be reached though through `Z:\media\myuser\drivename\`